# How to send a POST image url variable through a form in Laravel 4

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to upload an image url through a form in Laravel 4.

Without a framework, I would use something like this:

```
<div id="myResults" value="<php echo h($_POST['img'])"></div>
```

where the image url is sent to the id "myResults" by a javascript file.

In the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML = "<img src='" + FPFile.url + "' width='200px' height='200px'>";
```

I would use the `h($_POST['img'])"` value to get the url and then store it in the database upon the submit click of the form.

My question is how can I do this same function in Laravel 4?  Using the form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'artists.store')) }}

{{Form::submit('Submit', null, array(
                                'class' => 'button',
                                ));}}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ Form::file('myImage') }}`

Seriously, it's that easy! See: http://laravel.com/docs/html

Then, to retrieve the file: `$file = Input::file('myImage');`

See: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: but I just want to store the url.  I am using filepicker to store the url already, I just want to store it in my database when the form is submitted.

Comment: to simplify it down even further, I have the url printed out using <div id="myUrl"></div>;  how do I get this url to upload with the form?

Comment: You could echo the value with what I had said in my answer. Otherwise, I'm not understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding your question.
But equivalent of

`<div id="myResults" value="<php echo h($_POST['img'])"></div>`

in Blade is...

`<div id="myResults" value="{{{ Input::get("img") }}}"></div>`

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: will that upload the image url to my form when I click submit?